# How to pass two values to a single parameter in SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

This is my Store Procedure :

```
 ALTER PROC [dbo].[Details]

 @name nvarchar(20)

 AS

  BEGIN

 SELECT Id FROM Client WHERE name in (@Name)

 END
```

If i am passing one value output is Coming:

Like this i am passing:

```
EXEC [dbo].[Details] 'Monday'
```

---

For Two values Like this :

If i am passing two value output not is Coming:

To get this in which way i need to send parameter 
currently I am passing Two parameter like This

```
EXEC [dbo].[Details] ''Monday','Wipro'';
```

Thank u in advance

Comment: Ideally, pass multiple parameters using a data type that naturally *supports* multiple values (that would be table-valued parameters or XML). Alternatively, search for one of ~20 billion questions on here looking to split strings on commas in SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code to extract table from your parameter:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)=
'abc,def,ghi,jkl'
set @sql = replace(@sql,',','''),(''')
set @sql = 'select *
from (values ('''+@sql+''')
) a ( Value )
'
PRINT(@sql)
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Then use execution result with IN-condition. You can configure this part with any delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.[Details]
    @name NVARCHAR(30)
    AS
        DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @name = REPLACE(@name,',',''',''')
        SET @Sql = 'SELECT
                    *
                    FROM table1
                    WHERE username IN
                    (
                         ''' + @name + '''
                    )'
        EXEC (@Sql)
        EXEC [dbo].[Details] 'mohan,prashant'
```

Comment: i am passing values  in single parameter  from C# method to store Procedure  in some case my values  may increase 10  so i can't create 10 parameter